# Save Gmail attachment to SHARED Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, email-attachments, google-drive-shared-drive

Goal:
Update code below to save attachments to a "Test" folder within "Shared drive"

So far I've been successful in saving attachments to "My Drive" using the gmail2gdrive script found on https://github.com/ahochsteger/gmail2gdrive

This script uses `DriveApp.getRootFolder()` to find the root folder, but does not look at shared drives.
I have the "Drive" Advanced Service set up and am able to at least view up to 10 folders in the Shared Drive using `getSharedDrives()`, but have been unsuccessful updating the code to transfer files to a shared drives.

Comment: As mentioned above, DriveAPI is set up (This is the Advanced Service "Drive" v2).
Looking for a way to modify the code to using the advanced service to save the attachment to a shared drive. I'm unable to find the folder ID of the folder since Apps Script limits the shared folder results to 10.

Answer (score 1):

#### Move a file from MyDrive to Shared Drive

```
function movefileToSharedDrive() {
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById('');//fileid
  const fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById('');//shared drive id
  Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": fldr.getId()}]}, file.getId(), null, {"supportsAllDrives":true});
}
```

Drive API Version 2 needs to be enabled

Answer (score 0):

The Folder Drive ID can be found in the URL extension:
[Folder Drive ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/divg9.png)

Use the folders' Drive IDs (from above) to fill in the appropriate section of the code below (Copies files from desired folder into the shared folder):

```
function movefileToSharedDrive() {
  makeCopy("", ""); //("From My Drive ID", "To Shared Drive ID")
}

function makeCopy(srcFolderId, dstFolderId) {
  var srcFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(srcFolderId);
  var dstFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(dstFolderId);
  var files = srcFolder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var f = file.makeCopy(dstFolder);
    if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPT) {
      Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": dstFolderId}]}, f.getId());
    }
  }
}
```