# Save a Sheet to a specified shared drive using apps script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-drive-shared-drive

Our team uses several templates to create custom quotes. I am trying to automate these spreadsheets to be saved to a specified shared drive instead of having team members move them to the drive manually. I need help with code to apply in apps script for each template so when they create a sheet from these templates, it will save it to the specified drive automatically.

I have tried the code below but I don't think it fits our needs above.

```
function copytoMyDrive(){
  var destinationMyDriveId = "yourdestinationfolderid in my Drive";
  var sheet = "your sheet ID";
  Drive.Files.copy({title:'Copy of file',parents:[{id:destinationMyDriveId}]},sheet, {supportsAllDrives: true})
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70299310/7215091

Comment: - [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73197671/7215091